# If $A$ is a subset of $B \cup C$, then must $A \subset B$ or $A \subset C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be sets. Prove or disprove: If $A \subset B \cup C$, then $A \subset B$ or $A \subset C$.

I'm not sure if I should use element-chasing for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could go for a counterexample. 
$A= \{1,3\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{3,4\}$ would for instance do the trick.

(Also, often for this type of questions, drawing helps.)

Comment: Or more generally a counterexample where $A$ is not completely in $B \cap C$ but has some part in $(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)$

Comment: @mattapow kinda missing the "example" in "counterexample" :P

Comment: @djechlin True no concrete counterexample given, but the point was how you would find a counterexample for such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just take

$$A=\{1,2\}$$

and $$B=\{1\}, C=\{2\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that if A ⊂ B∪C, then A ⊂ B or A ⊂ C...

Because if A ⊂ B∪C, then not is the case (always) that all members of A are members of B or all members of A are members of C. For example:

Let A = {a, b}, B = {a, f}, and C = {b, c}. In this case, A ⊂ B∪C, but is false that {a, b} ⊂ {a, f} or {a, b} ⊂ {b, c}.

Answer (score 0):

As $B$ and $C$ are arbitrary assume one is not a subset of the other and that there exist $b \in B; b\not \in C; c\in C; c \not \in B$.

Then $\{b,c\} \not \in B \cup C$ and....

.... or to look at it differently.

Let $A' \subset B; A' \not \subset C$ (as $A', B,C$ are arbitrary, this is clearly doable) and $\overline{A} \subset C; \overline{A} \not \subset C$.

Then $A = A'\cup \overline{A} \subset B\cup C$.